# Returning records between 2 timestamps

Tags: sql, filter, time

I want to filter my results to only return the records between 2 time variables. In this example, I only want the results with time_stamp_local between 13:00:00 and 14:00:00. something wrong with my WHERE statement. Please assist. [image]

````
[declare @dateFrom date = '2022-09-01'
declare @dateTo date   = '2022-09-30'
declare @TimeFrom time(0) = '13:00:00'
declare @TimeTo time(0) = '14:00:00'
 
select T.external_id as Stop_ID,PC2.time_stamp_local,isnull(sum(\[in\]),0) as Boarding_Passengers,isnull(sum(\[out\]),0) as Alighting_Passengers,
T.LineName as Line, CAST(PC2.time_stamp_local as time(0)) as Time, CAST(Convert(varchar,@TimeFrom) as time(0)) as FROM_
from
(
select sp.external_id,sp.descr,sp.stop_point_id,L.line_id,L.descr as LineName
from apt..apt_calendar C
       INNER join apt..apt_journey_in_block JIB on C.network_ver_id = JIB.network_ver_id and C.period_id = JIB.period_id
       INNER join apt..apt_journey J on JIB.network_ver_id = J.network_ver_id and jib.journey_id = J.journey_id
       INNER join apt..apt_line L on C.network_ver_id = L.network_ver_id and J.line_id = L.line_id
       INNER join apt..apt_point_in_journey_pattern PIJP ON J.network_ver_id = PIJP.network_ver_id and J.journey_pattern_id = PIJP.journey_pattern_id
       INNER join apt..apt_stop_point SP on C.network_ver_id = SP.network_ver_id and PIJP.stop_point_id = SP.stop_point_id
where cast(c.calendar_day as date) between @dateFrom and @dateTo and j.company_id like '11%'
group by sp.external_id,sp.descr,sp.stop_point_id,L.line_id,L.descr
) T
LEFT JOIN \[I4M\].\[VS\].\[vs_passenger_count2\] PC2 ON cast(PC2.calendar_day as date) between @dateFrom and @dateTo and PC2.stop_point_id = T.stop_point_id and PC2.line_id = T.line_id
left join  i4m.vs.vs_passenger_count2_door PC2D on PC2.id = PC2D.passengar_count_id and PC2.error_flags = 0
WHERE PC2D.\[in\] != 0 or PC2D.\[out\] != 0 and CAST(PC2.time_stamp_local as time(0)) > cast(Convert(varchar,@TimeFrom) AS TIME(0)) 
    and CAST(PC2.time_stamp_local as time(0)) < cast(Convert(varchar,@TimeTo) AS TIME(0))
group by T.external_id,PC2.time_stamp_local,T.LineName,T.line_id--,CAST(PC2.time_stamp_local as time(0))
order by T.LineName
```][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqxSZ.png

I've made some changes yet the results still return records with timestamp earlier than 1pm. Not sure what I am missing.
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want casting the column to `Time` because casting to `Time(0)` rounds a fraction of a second while casting to `Time` does not. Consider:

```
select getdate(), datediff(MILLISECOND, CAST(getdate() as time),  CAST(getdate() as time(0))) delta
```

returns

```
(No column name)        delta
2022-11-11 18:54:15.590 410
```

showing casted to `time(0)` value was `18:54:16`.Try `.. CAST(PC2.time_stamp_local as Time) < @TimeTo..`. Note you needn't cast `@TimeTo` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Serg. Your response works. I had to modify my WHERE statement.